# CAS server and CAS service on same server/container

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, cas

I'm trying to get the [CAS service management app](https://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/Service-Management.html#installing-the-services-management-webapp) working with [CAS server (4.0)](https://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/index.html) on the same instance of Tomcat on the same server. The problem lies with authenticating to the CAS management app via the CAS server. Everything works ok until the management app tries to validate the service ticket with the CAS server and a `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?` error is thrown:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <serviceTicketRequest = true>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <requiresAuthentication = true>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <Request is to process authentication>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <proxyReceptorConfigured = false>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <proxyReceptorRequest = false>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter] - <serviceTicketRequest = true>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] - <Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider>
DEBUG [org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider] - <serviceUrl = https://myserver.com/cas-management/j_spring_cas_security_check>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Placing URL parameters in map.>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Calling template URL attribute map.>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Loading custom parameters from configuration.>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Constructing validation url: https://myserver.com/cas/serviceValidate?ticket=ST-56-mzPIDWgA0QMVj2ofdW1C-cas.myserver.com&service=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Fcas-management%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check>
DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator] - <Retrieving response from server.>
ERROR [org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils] - <Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?>
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Both the service url and validation url are over https, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. I know that the CAS server is configured correctly because everything works fine for services that are not on the same server as CAS.

The documentation says that the management app can be deployed along side CAS so I'm assuming that this can be done successfully.

Or is there a better way to authenticate that I'm missing? It seems like a waste to use https when both apps are on the same server.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

## Edit

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
ERROR [org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils] - <Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?>
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:326)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:305)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:50)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:140)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and the SSL debug when trying to validate:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1406390052 bytes = { 23, 201, 54, 229, 136, 4, 6, 166, 108, 226, 115, 79, 184, 27, 36, 163, 16, 248, 52, 47, 96, 149, 40, 24, 198, 81, 76, 10 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: myserver.com]
***
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 181
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-127.0.0.1-8021-exec-25, called closeSocket()
```

Comment: I think that's probably a problem with a certificate so, enable SSL debug in your server and post for us the log complete and full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not enabled a `Connector` in Tomcat's configuration file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` that terminates HTTPs. You'd do that by adding for your specific port (8443 in this sample):

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

See: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html